# Paypal sandbox subscription not working

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

PayPal subscription for sandbox not working.
Below is my code

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<!-- Identify the subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Weekly Digest">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">

<!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/paypal/paypal.php?action=ipn">

<!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
```

When I am checking in my PayPal account it is creating subscription profile and display next payment due date but on that day PayPal did not deduct amount from my account and also not sending any IPN on notify url.

Am I missing something in above code?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. The profile looks very neat in the manage section of PayPal. But still, the next payment due date never changes.